# Vaadin 14 themes - use "include"

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14, vaadin-charts, vaadin-themes

recently I've switched our CSS styles for our application and components to theme (added in vaadin 14.6). Right now I'm looking for an alternative to *include* parameter of @CssImport annotation.

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/custom-charts.css", themeFor = "vaadin-chart", include = "vaadin-chart-default-theme")
```

We have some style changes for vaadin-chart but we needed to include original *vaadin-chart-default-theme*.

Is there a way to achieve the same with the Theme support?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't possible at the moment, for the default Charts theme.

If you need to reuse some style sheet across components, you should be able to use the standard `@import` declaration.

For the Charts default theme, you probably have to use the existing `@CssImport` or the JavaScript `registerStyles()` method (from `@vaadin/themeable-mixin`).

Comment: Yes I have used the @CssImport and it works. So now it's the last occurrence of this annotation in our code. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to add: the way the default chart theme works is different from all other components, and I think we should change that in the future, so that it would not get replaced overwritten when you add your own customizations on top of it.